# Header included but declarations still missing?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    _set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When compiling this program, I get the following problems:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:4: error: implicit declaration of function '_set_error_mode'
main.c:4: error: '_OUT_TO_STDERR' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:4: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.c:4: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

The header **does** contain the function declaration and the macro:

```
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _set_error_mode (int);
# define _OUT_TO_STDERR 1
```

How come I get the errors? Notice that I also used the `EXIT_SUCCESS` macro which is also defined in the same `stdlib.h` header but for some reason GCC doesn't complain about it. Odd.

I'm using MinGW + GCC on a Vista machine.

Comment: Well, have you checked whether the declaration in your `stdlib.h` is "disabled" by some macro (i.e. an `#ifdef`/`#endif` block)?

Comment: Compiles for me with MinGW GCC 4.4.1 on a Win2K machine.

Comment: Regarding them being disabled by other macros: the header is a mess - it's large and contains nested ifdefs everywhere. Difficult to figure out what could be causing the problem. It seems that `__MSVCRT__` must be defined for the function to be available, but that didn't help. Btw, Neil has it working somehow. Are we using different `stdlib.h` files?

Comment: On my system those functions are not included if you are in a strict ANSI compile mode (i.e. -ansi is specified). It kind of makes some sense. Whether this is your actual problem is another matter entirely.

Comment: check by compiling with -E, searching the resulting preprocessed source for the contents of stdlib.h. You'll see exactly which lines are in or out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet works fine for me with MinGW 3.4.5

Are you sure you have your include file path set correctly?  Maybe the wrong `stdlib.h` is being processed.  Alternatively, maybe MingGW isn't defining `__MSVCRT__` which is necessary to get that function prototype (MinGW seems to define that automatically for me - I'm not sure how one would turn it off).

---

edit:

[tyranid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191953/tyranid)'s comment seems to have the answer - if I specify the `-ansi` option, I get the exact same set of errors as in your example.

Setting to CW and will delete if tyranid posts an answer.

Comment: Yes, -ansi was the cause of the problem. Thanks.